# How to get Gmail messages only from primary inbox?

Tags: 8.1, email, gmail

I have Gmail set up as mail in Windows Phone 8.1 with Lumia Denim.

Is it possible to get messages only from Gmail's primary inbox, but not from promotions and social?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set up rules for your inbox at [Gmail](https://gmail.com) itself and then export only your Inbox to [Outlook](https://outlook.com). This is probably a long way around but it should work. I've done this myself recently and have had no problems.